# File uploader not starting upload on form submit

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

I have a simple HTML form setup the way I normally set it up, but the file input of the form is not uploading anything. It doesn't show the little message in the corner `Uploading...(0%)` when I submit the form, and no matter what size file I put into it, the form submits immediately without starting the file transfer.

Any ideas?

```
<form id="sform" name="sform" action="save.php?id=1" method="post">
<label>Company Name</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="company" value="">
<p></p>
<label>Change Company Logo <span style="font-size:10px">(up to 1 MB) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#CC0000">*Leave blank if no change wanted</span></span></label>
<br>
<input type="file" name="logo" style="vertical-align:middle">
<p></p>
<label>Company Trademark</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="trademark" value="">
<p></p>
<label>Project Title</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="prt" value="">
<p></p>
<label>Project Completion Percentage:</label>
<br>
<input id="per" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="per" onkeyup="checknum('per')" value="10">
<br>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

add this attribute to your form

Comment: Yay! Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me ;)